# unable to pass value in jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp, web, web-deployment

I'm new to using JSP so I just wrote a simple email verification code where I'm getting an error for passing value. See the code for more info

```
<%
    String data="";
    String code="";
    String name =request.getParameter("username");
    String email =request.getParameter("email");
    String password =request.getParameter("password");
    String profession =request.getParameter("profession");
    data=password;
    String algorithm="MD5";
    data=generateHash(data,algorithm);
    code=getRandomNumberString();
    sendMAil(email);
    %>
    <%! 
    //password hashing....
    static String uname=name;//(getting error here)name cannot be resolved to a variable
    static String key=code;//(getting error here code) code cannot be resolved to a variable
```

my requirement is to pass Code value into key and similarly name to uname for use in functions
hope u got some idea on my issue
if any idea please help me
Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate more ? where you do you need to pass `name` and `code`  on the same jsp page ?

Comment: Instead of `<%! ` use `<% `. You are accessing scriptlet variable in declaration tag within same JSP instead use scriptlet tag.